# Best way to ship selenium with java application?

Tags: java, forms, selenium, web, browser

I am writing a java application which has one use: to fill out and submit a form on a webpage (without showing GUI of a browser). I have chosen Selenium for this.

However, how do I "pack" or "ship" Seleniums required browsers with my application? I.e. Selenium requires a browser executable to run the webdriver. I do not know which browser my target audience is using. How do I ship my application to run on any windows clients computer, without requiring them to manually install the browser?

Or am I on the wrong trail and there is a better option than selenium to fulfill my needs?

Comment: since you're not showing GUI, HTMLUnit would be perfect for this.

Comment: Well, I tried HTMLUnit but could not get it to work anyhow. Them I read in a source, that HTMLUnit was deprecated and Selenium should be used instead. The problem with HTMLUnit was that it apparently has a problem with the slightest imperfection in java script (e.g. an undefined variable), which is the case with my target Website/Form. Although the JS imperfection does not influence the site what so ever, HTMLUnit always threw an exception at me complaining about it.

Comment: the later versions are much better at javascript support... it always throws lots of errors, but Selenium will ignore those.  When you say "Selenium should be used instead", I'm not sure what you mean.  You'll be using HTMLUnit with Selenium.  So "driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();"  Your other option is to include a zipped version of a browser in your resources and extract it at run-time.  Caveat is you usually need to run it once to initialize everything you need to use Selenium with it.  So after extraction you launch the browser.  (I do this for XP support using Chrome49)

Comment: Slimjet is what I use for that: https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php  (If you use 49, you also need to use an older version of Selenium and older version of the chromedriver...)

Comment: Ah I see, I had a wrong idea about HTMLUnit. So its a GUIless browser which can be used with Selenium, right? 
If you mean the later versions are much better, do you mean the newest releases of HTMLUnit? I was quite certain I used the newest one but could not evade the java script error. How do I go about making HTMLUnit disregarding the error then? I think this would be the neatest solution but it would have to work with this slightly faulty js on my target site.

Comment: I use this version: htmlunit-driver-2.33.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar  I don't do anything special to avoid errors.  What exception are you getting?

Comment: Ah since I have deleted my previously failed project I cant remember the exact error code.. It was along the lines of: "java htmlunit '$' is not defined" and then provided a link to a java script of the targeted website. Upon further research I concluded HTMLUnit did not fancy said script because something was wrong with it (although I never made a call to it)..

Comment: @pcalkins Ok so I redid my project using HTMLUnit. I am back at my beloved error: "com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "$" is not defined. (some_website)". 
Any ideas?

Comment: shouldn't prevent you from automating... which version of HTMLUnit driver are you using?

Comment: you shouldn't have to re-do anything but initializing the driver... just add the version I use as a dependency.  You can get it here: https://github.com/pcalkins/browsermator/blob/master/lib/htmlunit-driver-2.33.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar (click "Download" button)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225568/discussion-between-daniel-jackson-and-pcalkins).